# Multer storage with router in express js

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I have this route, when I just give `desk` key everything fine, I can upload my image but when I use `storage` object it is not working and the route not found, also if I use `storage` with `app.use` everything working fine.

I can handle the issue by using `app.use` but I'm new in express, curious about why it is not working!!!

Thanks For any help :)

```
router.route("/").post(
            multer({
                //dest: 'uploads/expense'
                storage: multer.diskStorage({
                    destination: (req, file, next) => {
                      next(null, path.join(__dirname, '/uploads/expense'))
                    },
                    filename: (req, file, next) => {
                        next(null, file.fieldname +'-'+file.originalname)
                    }
                })
              }).single("image")
        ,
        controller.insertData // calling my insert controller
    )
```

Comment: I think that the path should be defined without `path.join()`, maybe if you try with `next(null,'uploads/expense')` ?

Comment: yes, you are right the problem is `path.join()`, Thanks @Runsis

Comment: I will add it as an answer so you can leave it as accepted :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `path` you defined in destination of `multer` should have been defined without `path.join()`:

```
router.route("/").post(
            multer({
                //dest: 'uploads/expense'
                storage: multer.diskStorage({
                    destination: (req, file, next) => {
                      next(null,'uploads/expense') // HEREEE!
                    },
                    filename: (req, file, next) => {
                        next(null, file.fieldname +'-'+file.originalname)
                    }
                })
              }).single("image")
        ,
        controller.insertData // calling my insert controller
    )
```